# Java UDP Server not working

Tags: java, udp

I've created this SpringBoot app, exploring networking communication with Java, over the User Datagram Protocol. I am running the the application in Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)

Here the main class:

```
@Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        socket = new DatagramSocket(UDP_PORT); 

        byte[] receiveData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        byte[] sendData    = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        LOG.info("UDP server init...");

        while (true) {

            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);              
            socket.receive(receivePacket);  

            String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength() );

            LOG.info("recived [" + sentence + "] from " + receivePacket.getAddress());

            InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
            int port = receivePacket.getPort();

            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length, IPAddress, receivePacket.getPort());
            socket.send (sendPacket);

        }       
    }
```

Here a client UDP class I've created to test the Server

```
public class UDPClient {

private final static int TCP_PORT = 5202;

    private DatagramSocket socket;
    private InetAddress address;

    private byte[] buf;

    public UDPClient() throws SocketException, UnknownHostException {
        socket = new DatagramSocket();  
        address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    }

    public String sendEcho(String msg) throws IOException {

        buf = msg.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, TCP_PORT);
        socket.send(packet);
        packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        socket.receive(packet);
        String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());

        return received;
    }

    public void close() {
        socket.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            UDPClient udpClient = new UDPClient();

            for (;;) {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                System.out.println
                    (udpClient.sendEcho("cullons"));
            }
    }

}
```

in my computer is working fine, then I deploy the UDPServer on a server, I got the ip using ipconfig

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 214.146.86.201

Then I replace "localhost" for "214.146.86.201", but I don't receive any message in the server.

I've done  `nc -vzu 214.146.86.201 5202` from my computer

with the result:

```
 MacBook-Pro-de-lopes:$ nc -vzu 214.146.86.201 5202
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
    outif (null)
    src 192.166.26.140 port 56827
    dst 214.146.86.201 port 5202
    rank info not available

Connection to 214.146.86.201 port 5202 [udp/*] succeeded!
```

But the server prints **null** on `LOG.info("socket InetAddres: " + socket.getInetAddress());` and `LOG.info("socket RemoteSocketAddress: " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress());`

I also tried in the server `socket = new DatagramSocket(UDP_PORT, InetAddress.getByName("214.146.86.201"));` with the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable problem could be that the 5202 port on your server is not accessible from the client. The port and their accessibility may not be the same as TCP but anyway there is always the possibility that someone in between is dropping your data packets.

The simplest workaround is to try to run both your client and server code on the server (214.146.86.201). If it can connect means there is definitely a communication issue which (seems) you can check using Netcat as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Checking_whether_UDP_ports_(-u)_80%E2%80%9390_are_open_on_192.168.0.1_using_zero_mode_I/O_(-z)). I didn't try it myself.